# PHP - "n" number of children in a list

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

This question is in relation to: [Group by in Laravel 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31556039/laravel-5-elequent-group-by-is-failing)

Essentially, what I have have is a series of "Groups" and each group can have a as many child groups as they want. So it could look something like this:

- Group 1

  - Group 1 Child

    - Group 1's child

      - Group 1 1's Child
- Group 2

At the moment, I am only able to display the group, and their children, using:

```
    <ul>
@foreach($contents as $content)
  <li>{{$content->title}}</li>
  @if($content->children->count() > 0)
    <ul>
      @foreach($content->children as $childContent)
        <li>{{$childContent->title}}</li>
      @endforeach
   </ul>
  @endif
@endforeach
</ul>
```

If I want to add more layers of children, I have to code this, with another `if` statement as well as a `foreach` statement. Obviously this is not practical when a group has n^3,... number of children.

Is there a dynamic, `while-loop` approach to solving this problem? Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is a **recursive partial** - a one that would load itself as long as there are some more group levels to be displayed.

```
// list_group.blade.php
<li>
  {{ $content->title }}
  @if($content->children->count() > 0)
    <ul>
      @foreach($content->children as $childContent)
        @include('list_group', array('content' => $childContent))
      @endforeach
    </ul>
  @endif
</li>

//in your template 
<ul>
  @foreach($contents as $content)
    @include('list_group', array('content' => $content))
  @endforeach
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I get "view not found" even though I have placed it within the same folder?

Comment: What is the folder path where you put it?